# How does Elmish.WPF marshall secondary windows into the main function?

Tags: f#, elmish-wpf

How do the various `#Windows` (`mainWindow`, `createWindow1`, and `createWindow2`) get marshalled as parameters when calling the [Elmish.WPF NewWindow code sample Program.fs](https://github.com/rfreytag/Elmish.WPF/blob/master/src/Samples/NewWindow.Core/Program.fs) as seen here ...

```
let main mainWindow (createWindow1: Func<#Window>) (createWindow2: Func<#Window>) =
  let logger =
    LoggerConfiguration()
      .MinimumLevel.Override("Elmish.WPF.Update", Events.LogEventLevel.Verbose)
      .MinimumLevel.Override("Elmish.WPF.Bindings", Events.LogEventLevel.Verbose)
      .MinimumLevel.Override("Elmish.WPF.Performance", Events.LogEventLevel.Verbose)
      .WriteTo.Console()
      .CreateLogger()
  let createWindow1 () = createWindow1.Invoke()
  let createWindow2 () =
    let window = createWindow2.Invoke()
    window.Owner <- mainWindow
    window

  let init () = App.init
  let bindings = App.bindings createWindow1 createWindow2
  WpfProgram.mkSimple init App.update bindings
  |> WpfProgram.withLogger (new SerilogLoggerFactory(logger))
  |> WpfProgram.startElmishLoop mainWindow
```

???

What plumbing is happening in .NET, WPF, Elmish.WPF that organizes the reference found at the top of [`NewWindows.xaml` to `NewWindow.Core`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfreytag/Elmish.WPF/master/src/Samples/NewWindow/MainWindow.xaml) so that the F# function `main` is called with the windows marshalled and passed in in the right order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As I finished the above question I determined what I think is the answer.  Left the question in case it helps someone else.  -RCHF*

For reference I have *thoroughly* read the the [Elmish.WPF Tutorial](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md).

In arriving at this answer I found [Getting started with Elmish.WPF, item #7 and #8](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF) helpful.

In Elmish.WPF, the ``` MainWindow.xaml`` file calls the C# code-behind file ``` MainWindow.xaml.cs`*must* have a`StartElmish``` function with the following code …

```
    private void StartElmish(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.Activated -= StartElmish;
      Program.main(MainWindow, () => new Window1(), () => new Window2());
    }
```

Here you see references to all three windows in the Elmish.WPF NewWindow code sample (see [C# XAML](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/NewWindow)) and [F# Core](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/NewWindow.Core)) being marshalled into the subordinate F# `main` function.

Comment: Did you mean to accept your answer? Your question is marked as without an accepted answer.